# UIKit<-segue->SpriteKit間の遷移でメモリリーク

Tags: swift

こんにちは

SwiftでiPhoneアプリを開発しています。

Segueを使ってUIKit用のViewControllerと
SpriteKit用のGameViewControllerとを行き来できるようにしたのですが
iPhoneシミュレーターで実行すると、デバッグナビゲーターのメモリが
画面を切り替えるごとに30Mずつ増加して頭を抱えています。
やりたいことは実現できたのに、悔しいです。
もしよければお知恵をお貸しください。

環境
OSX 10.9.5
Xcode.6.1.1

1. New -> Project -> Gameを選択
2. New -> File -> Swift File -> FirstViewController.swiftを作成
3. ライブラリよりViewControllerをストリーボードにドラッグし、Custom ClassでFirstViewControllerを設定
4. 矢印をFirstViewControllerにする
5. storyboardからFirstViewControllerを選択し、GameViewControllerにsegue接続。segueのidentifierにtoGameとつける
6. storyboard上のGameViewControllerを選択し、自らのExitに接続。identifierにbackとつける

各ファイルの抜粋は以下の通りです

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func returnMenu(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        println("Welcome back!")
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("toGame", sender: nil)
    }
}


class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            scene.viewController = self
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var viewController: UIViewController?

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        self.viewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("back", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

どうぞ是非よろしくお願いします。

Comment: GameSceneのviewControllerをweakにしてみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: weak var viewController: UIViewController?との定義を変更したところ、ついにメモリが減少（元に戻りました）これは本当にどうしたらいいのか頭を抱えていたので、ようやく実現できたと感激もひとしおです。See.Ku様のおかげです。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

メモリ「リーク」（使わなくなったメモリが解放されない現象）は、参照の循環が起きていることが原因で、クラスGameSceneのプロパティ`viewController`を弱参照（weak）にすることで、参照の循環を回避することができます。（コメント欄で指摘されているとおりです）

ここでは、それ以外の解決法として、タッチイベントに対するレスポンダチェーン（Respoder Chain）の活用を挙げたいと思います。

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func returnMenu(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        println("Welcome back!")
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("toGame", sender: nil)
    }
}


class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            // scene.viewController = self // 削除
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

    // GameSceneクラスから移植。
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("back", sender: nil)
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    // var viewController: UIViewController? // 削除
/* タッチイベントの削除。GameViewControllerに移植する。
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        self.viewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("back", sender: nil)
    }
*/
}
```

タッチイベントのレスポンダチェーンとは、タッチイベントを受け取るレシーバ（メソッド）が見つかるまで、タッチイベントはUIResponderのサブクラスの間を、順に受け渡されていくという、メカニズムのことです。SKNode（SKScene）で、タッチイベント（touchBegan）が受け取られなければ、UIViewのサブクラス（SKView）に渡され、UIViewControllerのサブクラス（GameViewController）に渡され、そこでも受け取られなければ、UIWindowに渡されます。けっきょくUIApplicationまで行って、そこでも処理されなければ、深淵の闇に送られていきます。
レスポンダチェーンを利用すれば、GameSceneクラスで、あえてタッチイベントを処理しないという方法で、GameViewControllerにタッチイベントを渡すことができるのです。

Comment: いやー、こういう仕組みがあるのかと驚くばかりです。私の読んだ３冊の本には初心者向けのためか、どれにも書かれておりませんでした。すごい！と驚くばかりです。本当にすごい。